# What tools are available for gathering statistical data about areas from KML files?

Tags: gis, kml

We have a KML dataset, specifically it's the Australian Bureau of Statistics Statistical areas.

We also have a set of points, and we would like to determine how many of those points are inside each of the ABS statistical areas for analysis.

So 
for area1 we might have 500 points in that area.
for area2 we might only have 150 points in that area.
etc.

What tools are available for gathering statistical data about areas from KML files?

Answer (score 1):

You'll need qgis and perform point in polygon test (http://maps.cga.harvard.edu/qgis/wkshop/pt_in_pgn.php)